# how to represent yii relations of two foreign keys refrencing one primary key?

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, yii

How can I represent relationship of this model:
we have a user table having PKey. Users are in two types: employers and workers -> The two tables hold an Fkey rederencing to user PKey.

I've coded sth like it in User model:

```
public function userTypeMapper($type) 
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'w':
            return 'Worker';            
        case 'e':
            return 'Employer';          
        case 'a':
            return 'Admin';         
        default:
            return 'Employer';          
            return 'Guest';         
    }
}   
/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    $entity = $this->userTypeMapper($this->u_type);
    return array(
        'entity' => array(self::HAS_ONE, $entity,  'u_id'),
        'projects' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Project', 'pr_u_id'),
    );
}
```

IN THIS WAY $entity ALTERNATES BETWEEN Eployer AND Worker MODEL!!

The problem is that it doesn't work!!! I don't Know Why u_type is not set when Project model fetches owner (in User). Actually nothing is set when relation is interpreted.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: The problem is when I access the user in Project model, nothing is defined in $this object! so $this->u_type is not defined too, and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, relation function calls when model is initialized, and it not have any attributes. When you `$user = new User();` your model `User` already have inited relations.
You have to set all relations:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'Worker' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Worker',  'u_id'),
        'Employer' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Employer',  'u_id'),
        'Admin' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Admin',  'u_id'),
        'Guest' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Guest',  'u_id'),
        'projects' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Project', 'pr_u_id'),
    );
}

/**
 * Get entity
 */
public function getEntity()
{
    switch ($this->u_type) {
        case 'w':
            return $this->Worker;
        case 'e':
            return $this->Employer;
        case 'a':
            return $this->Admin;
        default:
            return $this->Guest;
    }
}
```

When you want get entity model you just call

```
$user   = User::model()->findByPk($user_id);
$entity = $user->entity;
```